# how to compare strings read from a .properties

Tags: java, string

This code reads from a `.properties` file

```
protected String cfgReader(String arg1)
        throws IOException 
        {
    String readVal = null;
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("CFG.properties");
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(in);
    readVal = props.getProperty(arg1);

    in.close();

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CFG.properties");
    props.store(out, null);
    out.close();
        return readVal; 
}
```

but if I try to do something like:

```
if(cfgReader("var1") == "n/a"){...}
```

it doesn't work even if the `.properties` contains

```
var1=n/a
```

Comment: Look up the difference between `==` and `equals` method.

Answer (score 2):

Strings in Java are objects - they should be compared with the `equals` method, not the `==` operator, which checks reference identity:

```
if (cfgReader("var1").equals("n/a"))
```